# How to convert existing react app into npm package

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-router, react-redux, webpack-2

I have implemented a react app with react route, react redux and saga, I want to export this project as npm package so that its containers can be used in my other project with all the existing functionalities.
How can I achieve this? 
I am using webpack for bundling.

The issue I am facing is, I am trying to export the containers(HOC) not just components. I don't know how to make those HOCs to work with all the sagas and reducers which are being injected through the router, in the other project which imports the library

Comment: Take a look at this [Egghead series](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-publishing-to-npm) on how to write an Open Source library.

This covers a lot of basics, including publishing to `npm`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to create npm package of complete react project.
Just make sure u have implemented code splitting properly otherwise the bundles same libraries will be created multiple times.